# Validity of Seiberg-Witten theory and the understanding of notion "Effective field theory"

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, effective-field-theory, confinement, seiberg-witten-theory

I am reading "An Introduction to the Confinement Problem" book by Jeff Greensite https://books.google.ru/books?id=atwRBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=ru#v=onepage&q&f=false, and in the 8th chapter section 8.3 he speaks about the Dual superconductivity and Seiberg-Witten model. As a low-energy theory, Seiberg-Witten theory should be obtained by integrating out the massive degrees of freedom and when reading the original paper https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9407087, I thought that Seiberg and Witten succeeded to integrate out the $W$-bosons, although in indirect way. However, as mentioned in the book, the low-energy theory validity on large-distances is controversial.

Between any two objects, carrying two units of $U(1)$ electric charge there forms a flux tube, and in the effective dual Abelian Higgs model there is nothing that would allow it to break. However in the $SU(2)$ theory these charges have zero $N$-ality, and flux tube **must** break at some point via creation of $W$-bosons. So, the $W$-bosons **are relevant** to long-distance physics and for extracting the correct $N$-ality dependence of string tensions.

Then it is said, that Seiberg-Witten action is not the whole story, it is obtained by keeping the local terms with no more than two derivatives and not by integrating out the $W$-boson. Then it is concluded that Seiberg-Witten action is a good approximation in an **intermediate range**, much larger than the inverse  mass of $W$-boson, as far as I understand, but shorter, than the color screening length.

In what way one should think about the low-energy theory? I am used to think about it, that low-energy theory accounts rather well for the phenomena beyond certain energy scale, and the observed deviations from the theory occur only when the energy scale is high enough for some heavy degrees of freedom to become dynamical.